# how to use preventDefault in function onclick inside other onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in this example in react.js

```
<Card onClick="(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); goPage()}">
  <Card.body>
   <Media>
     <img
         width={64}
         height={64}
         className="mr-3"
         src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
         alt="Generic placeholder"
     />
     <Media.Body>
        <h5>Media Heading</h5>
        <p>
          Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque
          ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at,
          tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla.
          Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
        </p>
        <a href="#/" onClick="(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); downloadPage()}">Download Page</a>
      </Media.Body>
    </Media>
  </Card.body
</Card
```

But I need to both function's `onclick` work's independently, if I click in link `Download Page` I want only work it `downloadPage()` but not run `goPage()` and vice versa, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation` here is working sample with html:

```js
   function downloadPage() {
            console.log('downloadPage');
        }
   function goPage() {
            console.log('goPage');
        }
```

```html
    <div onclick="goPage(); event.stopPropagation();">
        goPage
        <div>
            <a href="#/" onclick="downloadPage(); event.stopPropagation();">Download Page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `event.stopPropagation()` method to be applied on the `<a>` tag: [MDN: Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent event bubbling. If you want to learn more, read about event bubbling and capturing at: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing#:%7E:text=The%20event%20propagation%20mode%20determines,propagated%20to%20the%20inner%20elements.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want to use stopPropagation instead of preventDefault, and this should onlly be necessary on the  tag, so it would look something like this:

```
<Card onClick={(e)=>{goPage()}}>
<a href="#/" onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); downloadPage()}}>
```

Notice I replaced the quotes with curly braces as that's the syntax I'm familiar with and found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), it may or may not work for you